# Removing Fragment by clicking/touching outside:

Tags: android, android-fragments, touch-event

I have some fragments that are added and removed from a `RelativeLayout` dynamically using code. one of the Fragments is a `ListFragment`, and as oppose to other my fragments that have a Close and Save Buttons this one contains only a list.

My goal is to close/remove this fragment by clicking outside of it on any place in the activity.

I have found the following code:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    // I only care if the event is an UP action
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        // create a rect for storing the window rect
        Rect r = new Rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
        // retrieve the windows rect
        this.getWindow().getDecorView().getHitRect(r);
        // check if the event position is inside the window rect
        boolean intersects = r.contains((int) event.getX(), (int) event.getY());
        // if the event is not inside then we can close the activity
        if (!intersects) {
            // close the activity
            this.finish();
            // notify that we consumed this event
            return true;
        }
    }
    // let the system handle the event
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

That closes a not full-screen activity when clicking outside of it, but i just don't seem to understand how do I find my fragment rectangle.

Could some one assist and point me in the right direction? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well I have finally figured this out:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent ( MotionEvent event ) 
{
    // I only care if the event is an UP action
    if ( event.getAction () == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP ) 
    {
        //and only is the ListFragment shown.
        if (isListFragmentShown)
        {   
            // create a rect for storing the fragment window rect
            Rect r = new Rect ( 0, 0, 0, 0 );
            // retrieve the fragment's windows rect
            currentFragment.getView().getHitRect(r);
            // check if the event position is inside the window rect
            boolean intersects = r.contains ( (int) event.getX (), (int) event.getY () );
            // if the event is not inside then we can close the fragment
            if ( !intersects ) {
                Log.d(TAG, "pressed outside the listFragment");
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;
                fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.remove(currentFragment).commit();
                // notify that we consumed this event
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    //let the system handle the event
    return super.onTouchEvent ( event );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add click listener to your container RelativeLayout. If fragment is up about action then activate your RelativeLayout's listener so listener only works while fragment exist.

Comment: didn't really understood your answer, have you read my question until the end?